# Don't do anything if CSV column is empty -- How do I achieve this?

Tags: csvsimple

MWE (actually not totally MWE, but I think it's easier to see what happens this way):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\setlength\unitlength{1cm}

\csvreader[head to column names]{jobname2.csv}{}{%
\vfill
\artist

\includegraphics[height=37mm]{\filenameone}

\includegraphics[height=37mm]{\filenametwo}

\comment
}
\end{document}
```

Content of `jobname2.csv`:

```
artist,filenameone,filenametwo,comment
Foo,example-image-a,example-image-b,Nothing
Foobar,example-image-a,,Something
```

When there is nothing in the `filenametwo` column, I don't want anything done (not sure how to express that properly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`csvsimple` provides a macro `\ifcsvstrequal{X}{Y}{equal}{not equal}` to conditionally execute code if the two parameters `X` and `Y` are equal or not (basically an `\ifx` of two `\edef`-ed token lists). You can use that macro in your example without the need for extra packages like `xstring`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
artist,filenameone,filenametwo,comment
Foo,example-image-a,example-image-b,Nothing
Foobar,example-image-a,,Something
Bar,,example-image-b,Anything
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\setlength\unitlength{1cm}

\csvreader[head to column names]{\jobname.csv}{}{%
\vfill
\artist

\ifcsvstrequal{\filenameone}{}{(no first image)}{%
    \includegraphics[height=37mm]{\filenameone}
}
\ifcsvstrequal{\filenametwo}{}{(no second image)}{%
    \includegraphics[height=37mm]{\filenametwo}
}

\comment
}
\end{document}
```

[image]